# WIKI VSTS TFS 2018 - Custom page with code

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, wiki

Colleagues, I tell in detail what I am trying to achieve.

I am using TFS in its version 2018, in it I have a project that contains a wiki.
From this wiki, I need to create a page that consumes a REST service and shows the information that returns the processed service.

Is it possible to insert logic into code within a wiki page?

If this is not possible, is it possible to insert the link of an existing web in the wiki navigation (see example below)?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1mC8.png)

Comment: Consider voting for the "Add dynamic Wii Content" suggestion here: 

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33310348-add-dynamic-wiki-content

Answer (score 2):

We cannot insert logic into code within a wiki page.

However we can add the REST APIs as link or insert the link of an existing web in the wiki.

Wiki supports Markdown, HTML tags, anchor links, and much more.
Please see [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/09/05/wiki-supports-html-tags-anchor-links-and-much-more/) for details.

To insert the link you can try below format:

```
[C# language reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/618ayhy6.aspx)
```

More information please see below articles:

- [Syntax guidance for Markdown files, widgets, wikis, and pull request
  comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=vsts#links)
- [Add and edit wiki pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/project/wiki/add-edit-wiki?view=vsts)